# I cannot solve the integration

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Please help me to solve the integration below:
$$\int (e^{x - 1/x})(1+1/x^2) \mathrm dx$$

Comment: There must be some typo as $$\dfrac{d(x\pm 1/x)}{dx}=1\mp1/x^2$$

Comment: Unless there is a typo as lab bhattacharjee says, the integral can't be found in terms of elementary functions, according to WA.

Comment: This integral cannot be computed. Are you sure it's not supposed to be $$\int \left(e^{x+\frac{1}{x}}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\text{d}x\quad\text{  or  }\;\;\;\int\left(e^{x-\frac{1}{x}}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\text{d}x\;\text{?}$$

Comment: Sorry. There was a mistake. But i fixed it

Comment: Brody your second option is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=x-\frac{1}{x}$. Thus, $\mathrm du=1+\frac{1}{x^2} 
\mathrm dx$. Now the integral is $$\int e^u \mathrm du=e^u+C=e^{x-\frac{1}{x}}+C$$

This is easily checked by differentiation of $e^{x-1/x}.$

Comment: Got it . Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help!